# Check if URl get parameter exists

Tags: php, get, contao

my CMS generates some parameter like this: domain.com/group?page_n531=2

The usual code is:

```
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
{

}
```

But my CMS changes the 'id' for every page, I just want to check, if a parameter exist, I dont need the 'id'. Can you guys help me with that?

Thanks.

Comment: Which CMS, that might help.

Comment: The CMS is Contao 3.2

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that you don't want the 'id'? And does id change to pId (for example)?

Comment: Its about the pagination from news, I want to display a special content if there is no parameter and if a parameter exists, the content wont be displayed and I need that template for several news and every news got its own id.

Comment: please elaborate what you want to achieve. it's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numeric part of the parameter is the id of the news module.

It is generated like: `$id = 'page_n' . $this->id;`

so your code (assuming you are in `mod_newslist.html5` template) should read:

```
if (isset($_GET['page_n' . $this->id]))
{
    // Yeah we are on some page in the pagination.
}
```

If you should happen to be in template `news_full.html5` or any other of the partial templates, you are out of luck, when hoping for a generic approach, as the id of the calling module is not available within there.

In this cases you will have to create different `news_*.html5` templates for each list module and assign it as news template to said module. Within there you can hard code the module id then.